# How to create a map with transparent background?

Tags: r, tmap

I'm trying to create and save a map with transparent background instead of a white (or any other color) one using the R package `tmap`.

Apart from what's in the example below, I tried using `bg.color = "transparent"`, `bg.color = NA`, and `bg.color = NULL` in both `tmap_options` and `tm_layout`.

Version info:

- `tmap`: 2.2
- `tmaptools`: 2.0-1

```
library(tmap)
data("World")

tmap_options (bg.color = "#00000000", basemaps.alpha = 0)
map <- tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI") +
  tm_layout (frame = FALSE, bg.color = "#00000000")

tmap_save (map, filename = "~/test.png")
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this simply a limitation of the package? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use the `alpha` argument within the layer of interest, e.g. `tm_polygons("HPI", alpha = .5)`

Comment: But that makes the polygon layer transparent, not the background one, If I understand correctly. I need *only* the background layer to be transparent.

Comment: Well, depends on what you want to do, but what is the background in this case, if you only have one layer?

Comment: That's the thing; there is no background. I want only polygons (+ legend, title and so on) on a 100% transparent background. In the example above, I want everything that's white in the resulting image to be gone.

Comment: if you use `bg.color = rgb(0,0,0, alpha = 0)`?

Comment: Nope, also gives me a white background.

Comment: There are 2 map modes in tmap - plot mode and view mode. Only the view mode seems to show background imagery like "open street map" etc. The plot mode seems to default to a white background. The examples at the link below clearly show the difference between the two modes. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tmap/versions/2.2/topics/tmap_mode. Could your issue be that you are expecting a format more like the "view" mode but that you are operating in "plot" mode?

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't solve my problem, unfortunately. I need the map to be static, in PNG format, so plot mode makes much more sense to me. I only need to replace the default white background with a transparent one somehow. But for the record: I also tried using `tmap_save` in view mode, the resulting PNG file had a white, opaque background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a trick!

I was looking for the same feature to draw a stack of maps in InDesign with outputs from R, tmap and I needed the background to be transparent.

Here my solution, given your code:

```
library(tmap)
data("World")

par(bg=NA)
map <- tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI") +
  tm_layout (frame = FALSE, bg.color = "transparent")

tmap_save (map, filename = "~/test.eps", bg="transparent") # Note the eps extension
```

**Caveat**: testing this with different output formats, I realized that it doesn't work with `png` or `jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the `png` function as the `device` argument.
The [`png` documentation](https://rdrr.io/r/grDevices/unix/png.html) says

> `png` supports transparent backgrounds: use `bg = "transparent"`. (Not all PNG viewers render files with transparency correctly.) When transparency is in use in the `type = "Xlib"` variant a very light grey is used as the background and so appears as transparent if used in the plot. This allows opaque white to be used, as in the example. The `type = "cairo"`, `type = "cairo-png"` and `type = "quartz"` variants allow semi-transparent colours, including on a transparent or semi-transparent background.

So you just have to change your tmap_save call like this (presuming you have cairo support compiled in).

```
tmap_save (map, filename = "~/test.png",
           device = png, bg = "transparent", type = 'cairo')
```

Comment: For me, it only works if I specify `type = "cairo"`.

Comment: @MarkusBauer strange, the default should be "cairo" (or "quartz" on mac I guess) if "cairo" is available. From the same link as before:  


`type: character string, one of "Xlib" or "quartz" (some macOS builds) or "cairo". The latter will only be available if the system was compiled with support for cairo – otherwise "Xlib" will be used. The default is set by getOption("bitmapType") – the ‘out of the box’ default is "quartz" or "cairo" where available, otherwise "Xlib".`  


What does `getOption("bitmapType")` returns for you? It's "cairo" as expected for me (on Fedora 37)

Comment: @MarkusBauer anyway it's probably better not to rely on compile time options anyway, so it's better to be specific! I've edited the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: It returns `NULL`